# How to call a javascript in plone site

Tags: javascript, plone

I have a html file which is under navigation portlet. I want to call a javascript from one html file which is in the navigation portlet. I put the javascript file under custom and registered the javascript in portal_javascript Registry. But i still can't able to call the javascript.

this is html page :

```
<script language="Javascript" type="text/javascript" src="calculatemyval.js"></script>
<form name="addition">
      <tbody><tr>
        <td>Value 1: <br>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input size="5" name="v1" type="text">
          in kg <br>
        </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
         <td>Value 2 : <br>
         </td>
        <td>
          <input size="5" name="v2" type="text">
          in cm <br>
        </td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;<br>
        </td> 
        <td>
          <input value="calc" onclick="calcvalue()" name="button" type="button"><br>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>Result: <br> </td>
        <td><input name="result" size="5" readonly="readonly" type="text">
        <br></td>
      </tr>
      </tbody>
      </form>
```

Here is my script :

**calculatemyval.js**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function calcvalue(){
    var h = document.addition.v1.value;
    var g = document.addition.v2.value;
    var res = 0;
    if (h > 0){
       h = h / 100.0;
       res = g / (h * h);
       res = Math.ceil(res * 10) / 10
       document.addition.result.value = res;
   }
  }
  </script>
```

Thanks

Comment: Way too vague and where's your code?

Comment: @DevlshOne : Updated my question with code . please have a look at it

Comment: Have you tried wrapping the `onclick="calcvalue()"`, like this: `onclick="javascript:calcvalue()"`. Are you using a Web Dev Tool at all like Firebug? You should be getting errors.

Comment: Yes tried this onclick="javascript:calcvalue()" also. still no positive result

Comment: If you're using jQuery, why not bind the function using jQuery's `.click()` method?

Comment: I m using  Mozila Fire bug only. Not others

Comment: I m using pure javascript not jquery or ajax.

Comment: You're loading the jQuery library on your first script tag.

Comment: Sorry,I dont need jquer library ther. I did check it again after removing the jquery libray from the script file but nothing happens

Comment: Maybe there's something about this portlet I don't know but you're not even getting any document elements with `getElementByName` or `getElementByID` in your custom script.

Comment: I tried it also. I called using id (getElementByID). That also didn't help me. Dont know whats wrong with it

Comment: Why do you keep crossposting?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `<script>` tags in a file that's already been designated as Javascript:

```
  function calcvalue(){
      var h = document.addition.v1.value;
      var g = document.addition.v2.value;
      var res = 0;
      if (h > 0){
          h = h / 100.0;
          res = g / (h * h);
          res = Math.ceil(res * 10) / 10
          document.addition.result.value = res;
      }
  }
```

This should be the only contents of your file.

Comment: I removed the <script> tag from the script file. Still its not calling the script

Answer (score -1):

HTML

```
 <html>
     <head>
         <script src="scripts.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

And your JS file has to be located in the same folder as your HTML file.

Comment: No, it doesn't... you can use relative and absolute paths.

Comment: @bzupnick : My html file is in navigation folder.As you told i put my script file in the navigation folder. but still its not working

Comment: take away that `language="Javascript"`. I've never seen that before.

Comment: It's no longer necessary, but it ain't hurting anything.

Comment: what about the `<script type="text/javascript">` and `</script>` in the JS file?

Comment: @bzupnick: I removed the <script> tag from js file. But no use